# RTK query doesn't fetch api data

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using RTK query to fetch data from a local api server (build with Flask, a Python framework) and show in component. I cannot see data, data is always undefined.

I've this when running the console.log

> useUsersQuery {data: undefined, error: undefined, isLoading: true,
> isSuccess: false} useUsersQuery {data: undefined, error: undefined,
> isLoading: true, isSuccess: false} useUsersQuery {data: undefined,
> error: undefined, isLoading: true, isSuccess: false} useUsersQuery
> {data: undefined, error: {…}, isLoading: false, isSuccess: false}

Here are my files:

userApi.js

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'usersApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', // local server from Flask
    mode: 'no-cors'
  }),
  tagTypes: ['User'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    users: builder.query({
      query: () => '/users',
      providesTags: ['User']
    }),
    addUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: '/users',
        method: 'POST',
        body: user
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['User']
    }),
    updateUser: builder.mutation({ 
      query: ({id, ...rest}) => ({
        url: `/users/${id}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: rest
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['User']
    }),
    deleteUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/users/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['User']
    })
  })
}) 

export const {
  useUsersQuery,
  useAddUserMutation,
  useUpdateUserMutation,
  useDeleteUserMutation
} = userApi
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userApi } from '../store/apis/userApi'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userApi.middleware)
})
```

userManager.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useUsersQuery } from '../store/apis/userApi';

const UserManager = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useUsersQuery()

  console.log('useUsersQuery', useUsersQuery())
  
  const handleOK = () => {
    console.log('handleOK', data, error, isLoading, isSuccess)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleOK()}>OK</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserManager;
```

Data is never fetched. Always have this in my console:
[image]

Comment: Well, what is that error it is giving you there?

Comment: nothing interesting, just : `error: {status: 0, data: null}`

Comment: That means that something is seriously going wrong with your `fetch` call - it returns a response with a `status` of `0`, which I've never heard of before. Are you mocking fetch here in any way?

Comment: Nope, I'm mocking nothing,  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users` retrieve data very well when using Postman for e.g. And the status is 200.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `mode: "no-cors"` which prevents JavaScript from ever reading anything from your response.

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#no-cors):

> [...]  In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response. [...]

You'll need to set CORS up correctly.

Comment: Doesn't work, removing "no-cors", throw throw this error : `Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
127.0.0.1:5000/users:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED` and no data are fetched : `{status: 'FETCH_ERROR', error: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'}`

Comment: You will still have to configure CORS correctly - which is mostly done on your server, not in the client. Please read the [docs on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). As I said, you'll need to set CORS up correctly, it's not just done removing this one option.